# When a character's arts are opened do they get all techniques?

Tags: ars-magica-5

Do characters with the Gift who have their arts opened to Elementalists have a 0 in all forms *and* all techniques? Or just a 0 in all forms?

Answer (score 6):

There is no special treatment between the tyes of Arts during opening - the 15 are opened at once with a score of zero (the apprentice does not get x in that season of teaching). see p.106, "Thus, in this season the apprentice gains a score of 0 in all fifteen Hermetic Arts, but learns nothing else."

Answer (score 2):

If you're speaking of the Hedge magic revised elementalists, they'd get all of their applicable arts for their individual tradition opened. They'd get 0 in everything, (note that none of the example traditions have a complete set of elementalist abilities).